# How to manipulate the selected data of a multisearch

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-select2

I have this code and I would like to know how to save the selected data in a variable to manipulate them as a json.

I have already managed to create the  values ​​through a json data.

```js
function customMatcher(params, data) {
     //show childs if search with parent
     data.parentText = data.parentText || "";
     if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
      return data;
     }

     if (data.children && data.children.length > 0) {
      var match = $.extend(true, {}, data);
      for (var c = data.children.length - 1; c >= 0; c--) {
       var child = data.children[c];
       child.parentText += data.parentText + data.text;

       var matches = customMatcher(params, child);
       if (matches == null) {
        match.children.splice(c, 1);
       }
      }

      if (match.children.length > 0) {
       return match;
      }
      return customMatcher(params, match);
     }

     var original = (data.parentText + ' ' + data.text).toUpperCase();
     var term = params.term.toUpperCase();

     if (original.indexOf(term) > -1) {
      return data;
     }
     return null;
}

$("#multisearch").select2({
     closeOnSelect : false,
     matcher : customMatcher,
     data : [{
       id : 0,
       text : 'Linea 1',
       children : [{
         id : 1,
         text : 'San Pablo'
        }, {
         id : 2,
         text : 'Pajaritos'
        }]
      }, {
       id : 3,
       text : 'Linea 2',
       children : [{
         id : 4,
         text : 'La Cisterna'
        }, {
         id : 5,
         text : 'Pajaritos'
        }]
      },
     ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select multiple id="multisearch" style="width:500px">
  </select>
```

Now I want to be able to manipulate the selected JSON values ​​in the search.

Thank you very much for your support!!

I am attentive to your answers

Comment: Well you could to store that selector into a variable.. I mean: var selected = $("#multisearch").select2... and if the node retrieve the data that you need it so, you can get the data. for example selected = selected.placeholder; and the value returned in "selected" must to be "Comienza tu búsqueda"

Comment: Give us an example of desired result please.

Comment: Example:

I want to store the texts 'La Cisterna' and 'San Pablo'.

Considering that these have a parent and an id

Comment: Have you checked this: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/retrieving-selections ?